# Fetch records from table based on count from another table with matching values and insert N/A if not found

Tags: sql

I have two tables as follows:

```
Table 1                       Table 2
Key1   Count              Uname    Key2
 a       5                xyz      a
 b       8                xyzz     a
 c      39                abc      a
                          def      b
                          ghi      b
                          lmn      c
                          pqr      c
```

I want to fetch records from table 2 based on Key1=Key2

Let's suppose If I fetch record based on a=a, so table 1 says 5 records should be fetched but table 2 has only 3 records. so it should fetch 3 records and for rest 2 count, it should place N/A along with the key in the table. I want to insert these fetched records in a table.
Any help will be appreciated ?

Comment: This is a rather unusual requirement.  Why do you need it?  Note that SQL is pretty bad at generating new data.  Rather, it is designed to extract data (records) which already exist.

Comment: Which specific RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you add the expected result  along with the question.

Comment: With Postgres you can use `generate_series()`

Comment: Supposing there are >5 rows in Table2 with Key2=a, which 5 ones should be selected ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this if you are on SQL server.

```
with data
  as (select distinct number as rnk
        from master..spt_values
      where number between 1 and 100  /*assuming that only differences of 100 exists, increase this if necessary*/
     )
   ,joined_data
    as (select t2.key2
               ,count(*) as cnt_from_t2
               ,max(t1.cnt) as cnt_from_t1
               ,max(t1.cnt) -  count(*) as diff_cnt
          from t2
          join t1
            on t2.key2=t1.key1
       group by t2.key2 
          )
   ,curated_set
    as (
   select t2.key2,t2.uname
     from t2
    union all 
     select jd.key2,'NA' as uname
       from joined_data jd
       join data d
         on d.rnk<=jd.diff_cnt
        )  
   select *
     from curated_set
    order by 1,case when uname='NA' then 1 else 0 end
```

Demo link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8244c58db2042cee6afa8dadc3b4221f

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE.

Here's a version for Postgres. But it should be analogously possible in all DBMS supporting recursive CTEs.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS
(
SELECT t1.key1,
       t1.count,
       t2.uname,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM table2 t22
               WHERE t22.key2 = t1.key1) c
       FROM table1 t1
            INNER JOIN table2 t2
                       ON t2.key2 = t1.key1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.key1,
       c.count,
       'N/A' uname,
       c.c + 1
       FROM cte c
       WHERE c.c < c.count
)
SELECT key1,
       uname
       FROM cte
       ORDER BY key1,
                uname = 'N/A',
                uname;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=33e6d408657eacc0304cf788a7f4276d)

The trick is to use `DISTINCT` in the recursive part to only add one row (per key) at a time until `c` matches the requested count of a key.